# TypeError: v1.isEqual is not a function

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I am using the `useCollectionData` hook in NextJs/React project. I am fetching some posts from my firestore database and I am getting this error `TypeError: v1.isEqual` is not a function

This is the code that I am using to fetch the posts.

```
const [posts]: [Post[] | undefined, boolean, Error | undefined] =
useCollectionData<Post>(renderPosts, { idField: "id" });
```

Comment: Error is not in this part

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV is correct. Please provide the whole code where `v1.isEqual` function located.

Comment: The function is from a package that I am using called `react-fireabase-hooks`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `useCollectionData`, it is not compatible with v9 sdk.

```
const posts: any = await getDocs(collection(db, "posts"))
```